# Unexpected behaviour of int and float multiplication in Javascript

Tags: javascript, floating-point, integer, multiplication

## Few Multiplications are not working as expected.

### Expected: No Decimal part.

[image]

### But few multiplications are working as expected.

[image]

### Is there a JS explanation behind this?

### My fix:

I used Math.trunc() to always have an integral part after multiplication. But I hope this shouldn't be required by default.

Comment: i's actually not js problem, but processor
https://ellenaua.medium.com/floating-point-errors-in-javascript-node-js-21aadd897bf8

Comment: Don't use Math.trunc() since that will give you the wrong answer for 4.1*100. Use Math.round().

Comment: note that even your 1.2 example probably isn't doing what you expect internally.  when you enter that value JS will actually interpret it as 1.1999999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875.  when you multiply that by 100 the nearest value that it can represent happens to be 120, which is why it seems to be "working as expected"

Comment: Hi @SamMason, Can you tell me how exactly have you arrived at this number? 1.1999999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875 I am trying a few things but can't get to this number.

Comment: I used Python's `decimal` module, but https://baseconvert.com/ieee-754-floating-point looks nice as well

Comment: if you prefer to stay in JS, that link seems to use https://mikemcl.github.io/bignumber.js/ to do arbitrary precision where I used `decimal`